# Clarifications on CHMOD

Tags: php

I am trying to create my first website, an auction/ online marketplace where users can sell stuff online.To do this, the users would add their items, and upload pictures of it through a form on my website.While uploading the forms, i check the file upload destination with

```
if(!is_dir($uploadpath))
{
    mkdir($uploadpath,0644,true);
}
```

and then createa directory to store the files if it does not currently exist.

However, i'm new to programming(The code above was copied and i do not know what CHMOD actually is) Searches on google tell me that CHMOD deals with permissions(i.e who can access the files on a filesystem) and show results that deal with how to CHMOD, etc but not what it actually is and does.

From the php manual,

```
<?php
// Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600);

// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for others
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for owner's group
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
?>
```

From wikipedia, i can see that the "write" permission allows users to add files, so i would probably need to give my users write permission to upload pictures?

Also i'm thinking that "Executing" means running a file (e.g app.exe) though i don't see how that would apply on a website since all pages are in html/php?

Finally, what does the "Read" permission do?If i wish for other users to view the pictures of items that have been uploaded, do i need to give them permission to read?
I wish for users to upload images , and for other users to view it, would read permission be required as well?

I plan on eventually hosting my first website with a webhost once i finish coding it.In this case, am i right in saying that the "Owner" as per the manual, is the webhost?If so,how would i allow my users to add/write their items and pictures onto my website?Should i use the code above where i CHMOD 0644 when uploading the filepath, or would i be prevented from doing so by my webhost.If so, what are the options available to me?

Comment: an online auction location for your first web site... pretty ambitious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "so i would probably need to give my users write permission to upload
>   pictures?"

NO you don't! You have to however give write permissions to your upload folder/directory - the folder where you wish to upload your files. Depending on the files you choose to allow for user upload, you can set the execute bit.

> Also i'm thinking that "Executing" means running a file (e.g app.exe)
>   though i don't see how that would apply on a website since all pages
>   are in html/php?

True. your php files dont need the execute bit to be set. Setting the read bit for the php files are enough for them to be interpreted by php.

> Finally, what does the "Read" permission do?If i wish for other users
>   to view the pictures of items that have been uploaded, do i need to
>   give them permission to read? I wish for users to upload images , and
>   for other users to view it, would read permission be required as well?

Yes! assuming you own your files and have apache as the group, you need to set the read permissions for both, to allow people to "read" or view your images!

> ...saying that the "Owner" as per the manual, is the webhost?

Not really, you can be the owner as well!

The idea or rather a good practice would be to chown the files / directories to owner:www-data , and 
set 0644 to the files, 644 means that files are readable and writeable by the owner of the file and readable by users in the group owner of that file and readable by everyone else.
and 
set 0755 to the directories, 755 means read and execute access for everyone and also write access for the owner of the file

Comment: If i am generating the folders/directories dynamically while uploading, do i give write permissions to the folders/directories by using mkdir as per the code sample above?Also if i were the owner, does that mean that i am operating my own server instead of hosting with a webhost?

Comment: To answer your second question first, when i refer as owner i mean the user who is the owner of the files / directories! For you to be the owner of your files need not mean that you are owning the server yourself! IT just means that you have an user account with the server where you wish to host your site, and the owner of the files in your web root is you. Although it might well  be the case that apache is the owner ( if its set that way).

Comment: If you are generating folders on the fly, then yes you have to give then write permissions as per the code samples above. Otherwise you wont be able to upload files in those folders

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to chmod files in PHP.  The only user that needs to read them is whatever user PHP is running as (typically the user the web server is running as).

Additionally, be careful to **not** store user-uploaded documents under your web server's document root.  Otherwise, they can upload whatever they want and execute it.  Always store user-uploaded documents by a name you specify (such as an ID number or ID hash without file name extension) outside of the document root.  Access these files with your own script and use `readfile()` or equivalent.

Comment: Sorry if this seems obvious, but from the php manual, it says that the default for mkdir is 0777, which is the widest possible access for CHMOD, if so wouldnt everyone and anyone be able to do as they wish?

Comment: That's correct.  And, why would you use `mkdir()` from your web script?  You shouldn't need to in most circumstances.

Comment: I'm planning on having users sign up before allowing them to upload stuff onto my website.As such, when i save what they uploaded, it would be according to their UserID in my database. E.g /User/1/item/20/item5.jpg In this case, i would have to create a directory for every user and every item uploaded which would require mkdir right?

Comment: you can create a algo of your own for creating the folder and the files in them. That way you need not create a folder for each user! All you can do is create a folder name by hashing the userid,file id and a secret key and make your directory. That way the reverse lookup is also easy

Comment: @Kenneth.J I wouldn't make a separate directory.  No need.  Once you are storing enough files where a single directory cannot work (due to filesystem limitation) you can split it out but by then you will be using a different method for storage anyway.